# Algorithm for graphing heap data from server memory, over long period of time

Tags: node.js, graph, memory-usage, heap

Right now I am collecting memory information on a node.js server every 100 seconds. I want do display the memory usage info as a graph on the front end.

```
const mem = {
  heapTotals: [],
  heapUseds: [],
  maxHeapTotal: 0,
  maxHeapUsed: 0
};

setInterval(function () {

  const m = process.memoryUsage();
  mem.heapTotals.push(m.heapTotal);
  mem.heapUseds.push(m.heapUsed);

  if (m.heapTotal > maxMem.maxHeapTotal) {
    mem.maxHeapTotal = m.heapTotal;
  }
  if (m.heapUsed > maxMem.maxHeapUsed) {
    mem.maxHeapUsed = m.heapUsed;
  }

}, 100000);
```

We aren't storing it in a db, or anything, just in memory. Of course, we keep pushing to that array every 100 seconds, it's going to start growing over time if our server is live for awhile.

I am looking for a fun algorithm I can use every 100 seconds, to refine the array, so that it has no more than say 2000 entries.

*I need a way to go through the existing array, remove past items, but average them with their peers, so that the graph is somewhat smooth.*

Say I have this:

```
[3,3,5,5,6,7,9,2,3,5,3,6,4,8,8,4,4,5]  (18 items)
```

I would reduce it by taking every 3rd item, and averaging it and the two before it, so it would be:

```
[(3+3+5)/3,(5+6+7)/3,(9+2+3)/3,(5+3+6)/3,(4+8+8)/3,(4+4+5)/3]
```

Something like that. However that is not really a complete algorithm. Does anyone know of the right/best way to do this so that the graph is accurate but doesn't keept growing beyond 2000 array entries etc?

Comment: Why not do what the various OS vendors do for their activity monitors and simply use a fixed-sized queue, where older entries drop off the end and you're only ever displaying the last 2,000 entries or whatever? Why are you trying to thin the data instead of rolling it continuously?

Comment: Use a low pass filter. FIR would work fine if you don't have any particular specs for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two separate concepts:  most recent values and average.

The user is likely going to want to see the most recent values and/or the average, but a combination of the two is difficult to derive any significant meaning from.  If the values are lost "uniformly", then without the context of timestamp, it means ultimately little.  Assuming there *were* a timestamp, the graph that this data would make would have points with significant holes in them.

May I recommend having three metrics:

- N most recent values - simply an array containing the last N most recent values.  If this update is happening every 100 seconds, a good N value might be 18 (as this would be the last half hour).
- N daily status checks - Every 18 values (half hour), you calculate the average of your N most recent values and add the average here.  If you have 48 of these, then you can cover a 24 hour period.
- Daily sum - Calculate the average of the N daily status checks into a single value representative of the average time.  This gets recalculated everytime the daily status check updates.

You may also consider having other values as well.  The max or min values may provide pertinent information regarding extreme cases that might be of interest.  The mean value may be more interesting to know than the average itself (50% above and 50% below whereas average may vary too much from spikes).  You may even want to calculate the standard deviation (+-3 standard deviations from the mean should give you 99.7% of all possible values).

Comment: anyone know why the original question was downvoted...it's a pretty legit question...not sure who would confuse "most recent" with "average"? I don't think you understood the question...it's about smooting and resolution of a graph. Essentially DIY smoothing algorithm.

Comment: I don't really understand why I'd want to see what you describe, or how I could usefully interpret it. This answer is attempting to describe what a useful graph _would_ show. What you asked for is a cool-looking graph with little information content, AFAICS.

Comment: The constructive critciism is helpful for me, but not to the OP.  If my answer is so unfitting to the question, please feel free to post your own.  There is no charge for posting answers AFAIK.